# Data generator from "yield" and Keras model.fit

Tags: python, keras, yield

I'm working with Keras deep learning module to train a model to be able to classify time series. Since there are lot of samples, I'm using data generator (yield) instead of creating an array. However, when creating the generator and introducing to the model.fit_generator (or also to model.fit) from Keras, there is no progress, neither an error, and so i don't know if there is an infinite loop or if the process is slow by itself.

Here is the code of the generator and the call to `model.fit`:

```py
def load_data(name, purpose):
    # purpose is a (1,2) vector containing (train/test, signal/noise)
    # next we obtain the correct path to the file depending on the purpose
    
    if purpose[0] == 'train':
        if purpose[1] == 'signal':
            aux_path = training_se_signal_dir
        if purpose[1] == 'noise':
            aux_path = training_se_noise_dir

    elif purpose[0] == 'test':
        if purpose[1] == 'signal':
            aux_path = test_se_signal_dir
        if purpose[1] == 'noise':
            aux_path = test_se_noise_dir
   
    data = pycbc.types.timeseries.load_timeseries(aux_path + '/' + name)
    return data
  

class GW_data_generator():

# This class will generate an array of temporal series, each row of the array being a GW series, and also will generate its corresponding
# result (0 for noise, 1 fopr signal)
# ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


def __init__(self, record):
    self.record = record
    
def generate_indexes(self,split):
    p = np.random.permutation(len(self.record))
    train_up_to = int(len(self.record) * split)
    train_idx = p[:train_up_to]
    val_idx = p[train_up_to:]
    
    train_idx, valid_idx = train_idx[:train_up_to], train_idx[train_up_to:]
    
    return train_idx, valid_idx
   
def process_data(self, name, purpose):        
    data = load_data(name, purpose) 

    # here i omit code consisting on signal processing
    
    # return an array
    data_ret = np.squeeze(np.array(data))

    return {'data_np': data_ret}


def generate_series(self, series_idx, is_training, purpose, batch_size, processing):            
    # arrays to store our batched data
    series, result = [], []
    
    while True:
        for idx in (series_idx): #tqdm.tqdm

            ######### WE APPEND A SIGNAL SERIES  ############
            aux_purpose = 'signal'
            parameters = self.record.iloc[idx] # returns the row of data corresponding to such series iloc
            file_name = parameters['Ref.Name']    

            # here we load the data and process it according to signal or noise

            # with processing
            if processing == True:    
                series_np = self.process_data(file_name, [purpose, aux_purpose])['data_np']
            # with no processing
            if processing == False:
                series_np = np.array(load_data(file_name, [purpose, aux_purpose]))

            
            result.append(1)
            series.append(series_np)


            # once appended a signal value, now we append a noise value

            #######  WE APPEND A NOISE SERIES  ##########
            aux_purpose = 'noise'
            if purpose == 'train':
                aux_path = training_se_noise_dir
            elif purpose == 'test':
                aux_path = 'test_se_noise_dir'
            it = np.random.randint(1, len(os.listdir(aux_path)))
            file_name = 'noise_sample{}.hdf'.format(it)

            # with processing
            if processing == True:    
                series_aux = self.process_data(file_name, [purpose, aux_purpose])
                series_np = series_aux['data_np']
            # with no processing
            if processing == False:
                series_np = np.array(load_data(file_name, [purpose, aux_purpose]))
                

            result.append(0)
            series.append(series_np)

 


        # yielding condition
            if len(series) >= batch_size:
                series_out = np.squeeze(np.array(series))
                result_out = np.squeeze(np.array(result))
            
                yield series_out, result_out 
                series, result = [], []
                
        # yield np.array(series), [np.array(chirpM), np.array(qratio)], result
        
        if not is_training:
            break
        

# train set of series

data_generator_train = GW_data_generator(record_train_series)
train_idx, valid_idx = 
data_generator_train.generate_indexes(split=0.8)
train_series = data_generator_train.generate_series(train_idx, 
 is_training=True, purpose='train', batch_size= 128, processing=True)
val_series = data_generator_train.generate_series(valid_idx, is_training=True, purpose='train', batch_size= 128, processing=True)

history=model.fit_generator(train_series, steps_per_epoch=len_train//128, epochs=nepochs, validation_data=val_series, validation_steps=len_val//128, verbose=2)
```

The final lines yielded by the process are:

```
I tensorflow/compiler/mlir/mlir_graph_optimization_pass.cc:116] None of the MLIR optimization passes are enabled (registered 2)
I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:112] CPU Frequency: 2199995000 Hz
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublas.so.11
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcublasLt.so.11
I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudnn.so.8
```

After those lines the process stops progressing.